# Replacing Placeholder text containing a variable

Tags: php

Hi I have placeholder text in my content from the CMS like this:

```
$content = "blah blah blah.. yadda yadda, listen to this:
{mediafile file=audiofile7.mp3}
and whilst your here , check this: {mediafile file=audiofile24.mp3}"
```

and i need to replace the placeholders with some html to display the swf object to play the mp3.

How do i do a replace that gets the filename from my placeholder.

I think the regx pattern is `{mediafile file=[A-Za-z0-9_]}`  but then how do i apply that to the whole variable containing the markers?

Thanks very much to anyone that can help,

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally was thinking you could use a function that involved json_decode, but strings need to be wrapped in quotes or json_decode doesn't handle them. So if your placeholders were written:

```
{"mediafile" : "file" : "blahblah.mp3"}
```

you could change my sample code from using `explode($song)` to `json_decode($song, true)` and have a nice keyed array to work with.

Either way, I went with using the `strtok` function to find the placeholders, and then a basic string replace function to change the instances of the found placeholders into html, which is just gibberish.

`strtok`, so far as PHP docs indicate, does not use regex, so this would be not only simpler but also avoid a call to the preg library.

One last thing. If you do go with json syntax, you will have to re-wrap the placeholders in`{}` as `strtok` removes the tokens it is searching by.

```
<?php
$content = "blah blah blah.. yadda yadda, listen to this:
{mediafile file=audiofile7.mp3}
and whilst your here , check this: {mediafile file=audiofile24.mp3}";

    function song2html($song) {
       $song_info = explode("=", $song);
       $song_url = $song_info[1];
       $song_html = "<object src=\"$song_url\" blahblahblah>blah</object>";
    return ($song_html);
    }

$tok = strtok($content, "{}");

while ($tok !== false) {
    if(strpos($tok, "mediafile") !== false) {
  $songs[] = $tok;
 }
 $tok = strtok("{}");
}

foreach($songs as $asong) {
 $content = str_replace($asong, song2html($asong), $content);
}

echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: Mate thats awesome, thanks. my musician buddy is about to be able to place her music amongst her copy. Thanks again. will.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example, using [`preg_replace_all`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), to show how it works :

if `$content` is declared this way :

```
$content = "blah blah blah.. {mediafile file=img.jpg}yadda yadda, listen to this:
{mediafile file=audiofile7.mp3}
and whilst your here , check this: {mediafile file=audiofile24.mp3}";
```

You can replace the placeholders with something like this :

```
$new_content = preg_replace_callback('/\{mediafile(.*?)\}/', 'my_callback', $content);
var_dump($new_content);
```

And the callback function might look like this :

```
function my_callback($matches) {
    $file_full = trim($matches[1]);
    var_dump($file_full);       // string 'file=audiofile7.mp3' (length=19)
                                // or string 'file=audiofile24.mp3' (length=20)
    $file = str_replace('file=', '', $file_full);
    var_dump($file);            // audiofile7.mp3 or audiofile24.mp3
    
    if (substr($file, -4) == '.mp3') {
        return '<SWF TAG FOR #' . htmlspecialchars($file) . '#>';
    } else if (substr($file, -4) == '.jpg') {
        return '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($file) . '" />';
    }
}
```

Here, the last `var_dump` will get you :

```
string 'blah blah blah.. <img src="img.jpg" />yadda yadda, listen to this:
<SWF TAG FOR #audiofile7.mp3#>
and whilst your here , check this: <SWF TAG FOR #audiofile24.mp3#>' (length=164)
```

Don't forget to add checks and all that, of course ! And your callback function will most certainly become a bit more complicated ^^ but this should give you an idea of what is possible.

Incidentally, you might want to use [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function) to create an anonymous function... But I don't like that : you've got to escape stuff, there is no syntax-highlighting in the IDE, ... it's hell with a big/complex function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick ansewer. Don't seem to quite be able to get that to work.  it outputs the original string minus the placeeholders but without the <swf tag etc.

Answer (score 0):

Read the regex docs carefully.

your pattern looks a little off.  {mediafile file=([^}]+)} might be ore like what you're looking for (the regex you gave doesn't allow for ".").

Answer (score 0):

you do something like that

```
$content = preg_replace_callback(
        '|{mediafile file='([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)}|',
        create_function(
            // single quotes are essential here,
            // or alternative escape all $ as \$
            '$matches',
            'return "<embed etc ... " . ($matches[1]) ."more tags";'
        ),
        $content
    );
```

you can see the manual of [preg_replace_callback](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Normal preg_replace also work but might be a messy.