# embed variable in longtext data

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to embed variable in a longtext field?

For instance:

description(field): The date is $date_var

in PHP:

```
$date_var = date('m/d/Y');
echo $row['description'];
```

Output:

```
The date is 10/13/2012
```

Please advise.

Comment: See if this helps: [Replacing placeholder text containing a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436688/replacing-placeholder-text-containing-a-variable).

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

$str = "The date is %s"

echo sprintf($str, date('m/y/d'));

Or use str_replace/preg_replace.  Don't use eval, especially on some data from a DB.